# Shiny downloadHandler two image format downloading error

Tags: shiny

```
radioButtons(inputId = "var1", label = "Select type", choices = list("pdf", "png"))
```

I used above radio button for choosing format and followed code for download file

```
output$down <- downloadHandler(
 filename =  function() {
   paste("The Plot", input$var1,sep=".")
 },

 content = function(file) {
   if(input$var1 == "pdf")
     pdf(file)
   else
     png(file)
   print(vals$gg1)
   dev.off()  } )
```

But it generating only PDF and no png out. Is there any problem with my loop

Comment: Your ID is not matching.  Try  `if(input$var1 == "pdf")`

Answer (score 0):

Need to add cairo

> png(file),type="cairo"